# Sqlite insert not working on reconnect

Tags: database, sqlite, blackberry

My problem is whenever I first create a database in SDCard and also making a table and inserting some values inside it is working fine .
But only once, if now i want to add some more data in my existed DB What i am doing is ,
I am going to the class where I have written the insert statement and inserting some more values but when i run my application and browsing my database in SQLite database browser it doesnot deflect any changes. I cant see my new inserted values

```
import net.rim.device.api.ui.UiApplication;
public class InsertDataScreen extends UiApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        InsertDataScreen theApp = new InsertDataScreen();
        theApp.enterEventDispatcher();
    }
    public InsertDataScreen() {
        pushScreen(new CreateDatabaseScreen());
    }

}
```

and my second class is this where i was creating the database and inserting value when i have done this my database created with one row
now i want to add one more row inside my database for that I have commented the Insert Statement when i done that i was expecting two rows inside but it doesnot changed...

```
import net.rim.device.api.database.Database;
import net.rim.device.api.database.DatabaseFactory;
import net.rim.device.api.database.Row;
import net.rim.device.api.database.Statement;
import net.rim.device.api.io.URI;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.LabelField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.RichTextField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.MainScreen;

public class CreateDatabaseScreen extends MainScreen {
    Database d;
    public CreateDatabaseScreen(){
        LabelField title = new LabelField("SQLite Create database sample and " +
                "inserting some value ",
                LabelField.ELLIPSIS|LabelField.USE_ALL_WIDTH);
        setTitle(title);
        add(new RichTextField("Creating a Database and will Add some data" +
                "MyTest.db on the SDCard"));
        try {
            URI uri = URI.create("file:///SDCard/Databases/SQLite_Guide/" + 
                                  "MyTestDatabase.db");
            d = DatabaseFactory.create(uri);
            d.close();
            d = DatabaseFactory.open(uri);
            Statement s = d.createStatement( "CREATE TABLE 'People' ( " +
                    "'Name' TEXT, " +
                    "'Age' INTEGER )");
            s.prepare();
            s.execute();
            s.close();
            Statement s1 = d.createStatement("INSERT INTO People(Name,Age) " +
                    "VALUES ('Uttam',23)");
            s1.prepare();
            s1.execute();
            s1.close();
            /**
            Statement s2 = d.createStatement("INSERT INTO People(Name,Age) " +
                    "VALUES ('Rakesh',26)");
            s2.prepare();
            s2.execute();
            s2.close();
            */

            d.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get Solved once a database created we shouldnot create it again.
and also cannot create the table again and again. Create should be executed almost one time.
And yes you should check the database and the table  already exist or not ....
if not create the database and table  and if database existed then insert the value u want to insert in the table ....
so the code should be like this

```
try {
            URI uri = URI.create("file:///SDCard/Databases/SQLite_Guide/" + 
                                  "MyTestDatabase.db");
if (DatabaseFactory.exists(uri)){
//d = DatabaseFactory.openOrCreate(uri);
d = DatabaseFactory.open(uri);
Statement s1 = d.createStatement("INSERT INTO People(Name,Age) " +
                    "VALUES ('Uttam',23)");
            s1.prepare();
            s1.execute();
            s1.close();
```

`Statement s2 = d.createStatement("INSERT INTO People(Name,Age) " +
                "VALUES ('Rakesh',26)");
        s2.prepare();
        s2.execute();
        s2.close();d.close();

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        add(new LabelField(e.getClass()+" " +e.getMessage()));
    }

}`

Answer (score 1):

You can't just blindly create the table every time.  If the table already exists, that statement will throw an exception when you execute().   You need to check that the table already exists, and then add the new column you want, or you need to keep track of a schema version, and then apply the incremental schema updates with the new code.

If this is just for development, you need to delete the existing database and start over.